# Is there a detection method available to detect a plane without using RADAR?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, air-traffic-control, wing, weather

If we don't have RADAR, is there any other method to detect flying objects?

All flying objects disturb the air around them. Is there any method by which we can detect that this air turbulence is from an artificial flying object or a bird etc.?

Comment: What about eyeball Mk. I? Works fine most days. On a more serious note, a wide range of the electromagnetic spectrum is suitable for object detection at a range, like infrared. Radar is just a part of it.

Comment: Your question has ambiguities: 1/ What is radar? If this is *radio* detection and ranging, then [lidar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar) qualifies. 2/ Detection from ground, airborne or from orbit? From orbit satellites use telescopes (visual). Airborne there are alleged technologies that [defeat stealth aircraft](http://nationalinterest.org/blog/the-buzz/how-china-russia-plan-crush-americas-stealth-aircraft-13708). Also [this](http://www.sentientvision.com/products/vidar/). 3/ Performance? [Sound detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_location) but low sensitivity.

Comment: Sure, there are ways of 'seeing' the disturbance of the air around an aircraft. But the problem with this would be that there would be so much erroneous noise from other things like: wind, cars, trees, etc. basically anything that could disrupt the laminar flow of the air would cause disturbances.

Comment: One of the things people used before radar was sound. These days the technique is called Acoustic Radar but of course it was not called that before radar was invented because the word "radar" did not exist. Do a google image search for "acoustic aircraft detectors" : https://www.google.com.my/search?q=acoustic+aircraft+detectors&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X

Comment: @slebetman: "*Acoustic Radar*" seems quite strange as radar means radio detection and ranging. Acoustic waves have nothing to do with radio... they are pressure waves.

Comment: @mins: Yes people are strange and misuse words all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Radar is, by far the most widely known and used of the active detection methods.

Passive methods include the use of visual and infrared search and track systems such as the F-14's Television Camera System or the Eurofighter Typhoon's PIRATE infra red search and track systems.

Comment: there's also the secondary radar systems, which aren't exactly radar, if you are thinking of radar in the sense that an electromagnetic pulse is sent from a transmitter and is bounced off of the skin of the aircraft and returns to the receiver at the radar site.

secondary systems are used to correlate the primary radar data with info from the air-crafts' transponders. the system sends out a radio transmission of various pulses which interrogates the transponder of any aircraft that receives it. The transponder then sends out a series of radio pulses on a different freq which the system RXs.